# variable definition, different output

Tags: javascript, variables

This gives correct answer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var numbers=[67,56,45,34,78,54,67,90,43,56,78,90,23,45,67,89,54,1];
var sita=0;
for(i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
    if(numbers[i]>sita){
        var sita=numbers[i];
        document.write(sita+" ");
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var numbers=[67,56,45,34,78,54,67,90,43,56,78,90,23,45,67,89,54,1];
for(i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
    if(numbers[i]>sita){
        var sita=numbers[i];
        document.write(sita+" ");
        }
    }
</script>
```

why?

Comment: sita is undefined :) here: `numbers[i]>sita`

Comment: Yep, `sita` is not defined in your second example.

Comment: sita is undefined. so '>' comapre operator is not working

Comment: I think, you didn't have programming knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

as others have mentioned sita is undefined in the second example.

a larger or smaller comparison against undefined - in that specific situation of yours - always yields false, no matter against what you compare.

so, your expression translates to

```
if (false)
```

**EDIT:** 
I completely missed line 5 of the second example because so many people wrote that the variable sita was undefined when in fact just it's value is undefined. So enabling strict mode won't do much good here. Anyways, just for reference, my original post:

> To avoid mistakes like that you should always (or if not always then
>   at least while debugging) use the strict mode (available since
>   ECMAScript 5).
>
> ```
> "use strict";
> ```
>
> link: 
>   [What does "use strict" do in JavaScript, and what is the reasoning behind it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it)

Comment: This is not proper answer, because in this case sita itself is undefined, not value of sita, so it is not equivalent of `if(false)`, instead it will throw exception

Comment: write this in console: `undeclaredvariable > 5`. it will throw exception. then try this: `var second; second > 5;` it will log false. then write `typeof undeclaredvariable` and `typeof second` both will be "undefined". see difference? :)

Comment: I am talking about the specific example of the OP. try it. copy it to an html page. run it. tell me WHERE EXACTLY an error is thrown and reevaluate if i deserved that downvote. http://jsbin.com/uhawub/1/

Comment: @MichaelGeary `if(numbers[i]>sita){ var sita=numbers[i]; ...` sita is declared after it is used in if statement, so I thought sequence matters, but appears I was wrong. My apologies :)

Comment: We are all learning here something new every day, this was important fact for me, thanks

Comment: @karaxuna - I deleted my previous comment by mistake, sorry! Here's a repeat so no one gets confused reading the thread. :-) In the second script in the question, there is a `var sita` in the middle, and that means that at the beginning of the script the sita variable does exist, has the `undefined` value, and will not give a reference error. When a function or global script is executed, all variables come into existence before any of the code is executed (commonly called "hoisting"). The effect is as if the `var sita` (but not the assignment) is moved to the top of the script.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code example `sita` is defined just before the `for` **and within** your if statement. I would assume that your second definition `var sita = numbers[i]` should look like `sita = numbers[i]`.

In your second code example **sita is not defined before use** - only within your if. So `sita` is **undefined** and your if condition *won't check out* and *nothing will be printed*.

Answer (score 0):

Say you're the interpreter. And you've reached the line `if(numbers[i]>sita){` what would you think, what value has the `sita` variable?

You have to define variabls before using them (like in the first example). Otherwise interpreter won't know what means that word.

Comment: That's not quite correct. In the second example, the `sita` variable *does* have a value, `undefined`, at the very beginning of the script - even before the `var sita = 0;` statement. Remember that all variables in a function or script come into existence before any of the code is actually executed. (Commonly called "hoisting".)